# Add two lists of dictionary without common elements

Tags: python, list, dictionary, data-structures

```
a = [{
        "class": "class1",
        "subclass": "subclass1"
      }]

b = [{
    'class': 'class1',
    'subclass': 'subclass2'
     },
    {
    'class': 'class3',
    'subclass': 'subclass3'
     }]

final_result= [{
        "class": "class1",
        "subclass": "subclass1"
      },
      {
       'class': 'class3',
       'subclass': 'subclass3'
     }]
```

I want to add list 'b' with 'a' and exclude the element if another element with same class exists in list 'a' as in the above code both lists have a dict with common class - 'class1'

Comment: so in this case the whole list b is excluded? because both class and subclass exist in list a

Comment: I have updated the question with better explanation

Comment: what if you have class='class3', subclass='subclass1'? In this case subclass will be repeated, should the whole dictionary be discarted? From the key names if something has class3 and subclass1 should not be the same as something having class1, subclass1. But this contradicts the title saying "without common elements".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can create a `set` of a's classes and loop over b to keep onle the elements with new classes:

```
existing = set(d['class'] for d in a)
# {'class1'}

c = a + [d for d in b if d['class'] not in existing]
```

output:

```
[{'class': 'class1', 'subclass': 'subclass1'},
 {'class': 'class3', 'subclass': 'subclass3'}]
```